# SQL return a Float data type number as blank if null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a float datatype column. I want the null values in that to be returned as blank when I select it.
I tried this:

```
case when Column is null then '' else Column end
```

but it returns an error:

```
Invalid Syntax for float
```

Comment: If this is so that your presentation layer doesn't show the word `NULL` to a human being, then you should be doing this in your presentation layer.  *(Your application, report, whatever.)*  It is nearly universally a bad idea to deal with presentation considerations in your data layer.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? How is this number going to be used? Numbers aren't text so blank has no meaning for numeric data. It's either 0 or missing/null. If you want to *display* an empty space instead of a null eg in a form or report, you can modify how numbers are rendered. Most reporting tools allow custom formatting or special handling of nulls for example.

Answer (score 1):

`''` is a blank string and can't be implicitly cast to `float`. You may either return `NULL` or cast the output to text.

```
select case when Col is null then '' else Col::text end from t;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b813ea1c22100c062c9806c0b07c17f9)